# Portforwarding tp-link

Tags: port-forwarding

I want to port forward a game. Garry's mod. The problem is, I have no idea what to put in the fields(Sorry long time ago since I port forwarded a game). People always have other fields when I search on internet. I know I need port 27000 and 27015. Too bad I cant post pictures but it looks like this:

```
Service Port:    (XX-XX or XX)
Internal Port:   (XX, Only valid for single Service Port or leave it blank)
IP Address:     
Protocol:   all/tcp/udp
Status:     
Common Service Port: dns/ftp/gopher/http/nntp/pop3/pptp/smtp/sock/telnet
```

Can someone please tell me what to fill in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port forwarding looks worse than it is when logged into the router, the service port will be 27000-27015, put your local ip address i.e. (192.168.x.x), everything else is ok, make sure you go into the network section of your TPlink router and set it to keep your IP address so it doesn't change.

Comment: when i test it. It says my ports arent open.